# Tkinter window popup to front

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a timer program using Tkinter, I want to make it so that after timer runs out the tkinter window popups on top of every other applications i have opened. Is it possible to do so and if so, how may i achieve this functionality

I don't have a clue how to tackle this issue

Answer (score 0):

To make your Tkinter timer program bring its window to the front when the timer runs out, you can use a few platform-specific methods, as this functionality typically depends on the underlying operating system. Below are examples for Windows and macOS:

**For Windows:**
You can use the `pywin32` library to bring the Tkinter window to the front. First, make sure to install the `pywin32` library if you haven't already.

You can use the following code to bring the Tkinter window to the front after the timer runs out:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import win32gui

def countdown(timer):
    while timer > 0:
        timer_label.config(text=f"Time left: {timer} seconds")
        timer -= 1
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

    # After the timer runs out, bring the window to the front
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.lift()
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(root.winfo_id())

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Timer Program")

timer_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 16))
timer_label.pack()

# Set the timer duration (e.g., 5 seconds)
timer_duration = 5

countdown(timer_duration)

root.mainloop()
```

**For macOS:**
On macOS, you can use the `osascript` command to achieve this. You can use the `subprocess` module to run the AppleScript to bring the window to the front. Make sure to adjust the timer duration accordingly:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import subprocess

def countdown(timer):
    while timer > 0:
        timer_label.config(text=f"Time left: {timer} seconds")
        timer -= 1
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

    # After the timer runs out, bring the window to the front
    osa_script = 'tell application "Python" to activate'
    subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', osa_script])

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Timer Program")

timer_label = tk.Label(root, text="", font=("Helvetica", 16))
timer_label.pack()

# Set the timer duration (e.g., 5 seconds)
timer_duration = 5

countdown(timer_duration)

root.mainloop()
```

These examples will bring the Tkinter window to the front when the timer runs out. Remember to adjust the timer duration to your needs.

Comment: Using `time.sleep` with `root.update` is discouraged. Please look at the [`.after`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25753719/11106801) method.

Answer (score 0):

```py
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**